# Node duplex stream doesn't actually emit data when read

Tags: javascript, node.js, duplex, node-streams

I'm working on a data-sink of sorts that is eventually to be used for Key-Value object streams in nodejs.

I've stumbled across duplex streams and started playing with them a bit to get my feet wet, but everything I try seems to not work.

At present, I've got this duplex stream:

```
class StorageStream extends stream.Duplex {
  constructor() {
    super({
      objectMode: true
    })

    this.values = new Map();
    this.entries = this.values.entries();
  }

  _write(data, encoding, next) {
    const { key, value } = data;

    this.values.set(key, value);

    next();
  }

  _read() {
    const next = this.entries.next();

    if (next.value) {
      this.push(next.value);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a SUPER CONTRIVED example, but essentially, when I write to this stream it should store the key and value in the Map, and when I read from this stream it should start reading from the map and passing them down the stream. However, this doesn't work, doing basically the below

```
const kvstream = createKVStreamSomeHow(); // a basic, readable stream with KV Pairs

const logger = createLoggerStreamSomeHow(); // writable stream, logs the data coming through

const storage = new StorageStream();

kvstream.pipe(storage).pipe(logger);
```

causes the process to just end. So I guess I'm just a bit confused as to what I'm supposed to be doing inside of the `_read` method.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations from the code provided by OP:

1. The iterator that loops over the keys returned by `read()` is generated before any keys have been set, in: `this.entries = this.values.entries();`. Consequently, calling read() never produce output.
2. If a new key is set in the Map, it won't be pushed onto the read buffer for subsequent writables to process

The duplex implementation can be simplified by using the built-in [Transform (docs)](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) constructor. The transform constructor is perfect for store-and-forward scenarios.

This is an example of how a stream Transform could be applied in this scenario. Note that the `pipeline()` function is not required, and has been used in this example to simplify awaiting that the readable to have emitted all its data:

```js
const { Writable, Readable, Transform, pipeline } = require('stream');

class StorageStream extends Transform {
  constructor() {
    super({
      objectMode: true
    })

    this.values = new Map();
  }

  _transform(data, encoding, next) {
    const { key, value } = data;

    this.values.set(key, value);
    console.log(`Setting Map key ${key} := ${value}`)

    next(null, data);
  }
}

(async ()=>{
  await new Promise( resolve => {
    pipeline(
      new Readable({
        objectMode: true,
        read(){
          this.push( { key: 'foo', value: 'bar' } );
          this.push( null );
        }
      }),
      new StorageStream(),
      new Writable({
        objectMode: true,
        write( chunk, encoding, next ){
          console.log("propagated:", chunk);
          next();
        }
      }),
      (error) => {
        if( error ){
          reject( error );
        }
        else {
          resolve();
        }
      }
    );
  });
})()
  .catch( console.error );
```

This produces the following output

```
> Setting Map key foo := bar
> propagated: { key: 'foo', value: 'bar' }
```

And can be used as

```
kvstream.pipe(new StorageStream()).pipe(logger);
```